# Javascript console.log works but input value is undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm having some trouble with a simple function that makes an ajax call to get the link for a specific category and then puts the value at an input.

My Ajax Call:

```
function GetCategoryInfo(){
var form  = document.getElementById('add-info');
var formData = new FormData(form);
formData.append('caller', 'Info');
$.ajax({ url: '../inc/call.php',
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(output) {
        console.log(output);
        return output;
    }
});
}
```

My function:

```
$('#card_category').change(function(){
$('#card_slug').val(GetCategoryInfo() + "/" + GetNameInfo());
CheckPokemonSlug();
})
```

Please ignore function GetNameInfo() since its working very well.
My problem occurs when the change select item happens.
It always fill the input with "undefined/text from function GetNameInfo()"

The worst thing it that the console.log outputs the right information that should be in the input form.

Any suggestions on this?
Since I call the isn't this supposed to work. Get's the information and then set it to input.

Comment: Ajax Perform an asynchronous HTTP request.

Comment: So how can I acomplish this task?

Comment: You've to understand the concept, read and read and read then you'll accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an `AJAX` call, it is asynchronous, however, your selection is synchronously done. Therefore the `function` immediately returns an `undefined`, and only later returns the asynchronous value, but you are no longer listening to that value.

You could try assignment of your input text from where your `console.log` is, at that point, the call has already returned.

Comment: If the console log works in that point, the return ouput shouldn't work either?!

Comment: Your return is irrelevant at that point, your function has already returned from when you called it to set your input text, also please don't down vote my answer, I am trying to help you and I am right, you're just not understanding

Comment: I didn't downvoted you. That would be maybe another user. So, what's the point? There's any way to check if the function has a value? Like wait until ajax call is completed? I'm completly lost and as I'm learning I really don't know where and how to search.

Comment: Set your input value from where the console.log is

Comment: @Tiago: if(typeof <value> != 'undefined') ...

Comment: @Tiago When you call `GetCategoryInfo()` it will perform an ajax request that will wait for the answer since it's an "asynchronous" method. when the ajax is waiting the `GetCategoryInfo()`  is a "synchronous" method ant it will not wait it will return immediately when the result isn't yet ready that why it will return `undefined`

Comment: @SerjSagan that won't work since I need to join two different values. One comes from select (GetCategoryInfo) and another from an input (GetNameInfo).

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Thanks for your comment. I already noticed that when your first comment. My problem is, how can I wait until I have the result and to that? Thanks.

Comment: So the answer is : the event should look like `$('#card_category').change(GetCategoryInfo);` and the callback should set the value like `success: function(output) { $('#card_slug').val(output + "/" + GetNameInfo());CheckPokemonSlug(); }`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Thanks. Sorry for this, but I'm learning and there are some concepts that are diving me crazy. I searched and searched and this makes totally sense right now! Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Glad I could help brother, happy coding.